# CSV reader repeatedly reading 1 line

Tags: python, csv

I have a `csv.reader` reading a file, but repeatedly reading the same line.

```
import csv

with open('mydata.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        while i < 10:
            print row
            i=i+1
```

The code prints the second row (as I want to skip the header) 10 times.

Comment: If you don't want to `print` the same `row` multiple times, why on earth do you have a `while` loop?! *(And if it should be there, `for _ in range(10)` is more Pythonic.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is doing exactly what you told it to do...
(and also, your title is misleading: the reader is reading the row only once, you are simply printing it 10 times)

```
reader.next() # advances to second line
for row in reader: # loops over remaining lines
    while i < 10: # loops over i
        print row # prints current row - this would be the second row in the first forloop iteration... 10 times, because you loop over i.
        i=i+1 # increments i, so the next rows, i is already >=10, your while-loop only affects the second line.
```

Why do you have that while loop in the first place? 
You could easily do something like:

```
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   for rownum, row in enumerate(reader):
     if rownum: #skip first line
        print row
```